# C# Windows Form: Declared/initialized a FileStream object, builds successfully, doesn't run

Tags: c#, windows, forms, filestream, streamreader

I'm using a Windows Form to make a Book Catalog (ISBNs, titles, authors, etc.). I have a sample .txt file that I want to be read, then added to my ListBox. Each line of the .txt file is to be an item in the ListBox. The draft version of the Form works great, but I want to be able to load a .txt file of books into my Form. Here's the issue: declaring and initializing a FileStream object as such...

```
static FileStream file = new FileStream(FILENAME, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

...allows my program to build successfully, but it doesn't run. It doesn't even throw an error. Instead, I get something that looks like this (screenshot): https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCuBk.jpg And I know it's not the StreamReader object because a StreamReader needs a FileStream object in the first place (for the constructor).

Any ideas? Any way in which my limited knowledge is preventing me from asking a better question?

Comment: attach the image here, don't link

Comment: I unfortunately don't have enough reputation to post images yet. I recently made my account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I don't know what you are trying to do with the stream but I would first of all use a using statement (how you are using it I mean)

```
using (FileStream fileStream = File.Open(@"C:\somefile", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    ...
}
```

edit:

I would suggest something like this from (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287535(v=vs.71).aspx)

```
using(var reader = new StreamReader(@"c:\test.txt")){
    while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        ListBox.Items.Add(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: Also - notice File.open instead of new FileStream

Comment: I'm doing something to the effect of while(line_from_txt_file != null) { ListBox.Items.Add(line_from_txt_file);}

Comment: thank you for your help! I'm not entirely sure why my textbook's example doesn't use a "using" statement...I'll be sure to figure that out.